# Returning a list to another list from a for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, extend

Hi all I have a list that is created at the end of a for loop. The last line is

```
newlist.append(variable)
```

I run the loop and it returns a value but it is overwrited on the next loop through. Thus What i want to do is return the newlist to the newlist2 so that when i iterate over the loop i can get all the lists into the newlist2 such that all values are returned.

For example at the end of the first loop the list is

```
newlist = ['name', 20, 50, 70]
```

I want to append that to

```
newlist2 = [['name', 20, 50, 70]]
```

then the second time through i get

```
 newlist = ['name', 50, 70, 90]
```

and I want to append that to the newlist2 such that

```
newlist2 =     [['name', 20, 50, 70], ['name', 50, 70, 90]]
```

Is this possible?? Am i doing this wrong or need to use extend instead??

EDIT: This is the code that has been construted with help already.

```
newlist=[]
for each in StationList:
    if calculateDistance(Eastingbase, Northingbase, each[1], each[2])< radius: 
        Relevantfilename = each[0]
        print Relevantfilename
        with open(Relevantfilename, 'rU') as input: 
            dL= list(csv.reader(input))
            total2 = sum(int(i[2]) for i in dL if '2011' in i)
            print total2, "is average for", each[0]
            try:
                average = total2 / float(len([int(i[2]) for i in dL if '2011' in i]))
                print average,"is average for", each[0]
            except ZeroDivisionError: 
                print 0
            each.append(average)  
        print each
        newlist.append(each)
```

Comment: Yes you can do it with `append` only. Can you show your code?

Comment: Just add the code you have to your question.

Comment: @RohitJain code is added can the list be returned??

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
>>> def list_of_list():
...     all_lists = []
...     for _ in range(3):
...         all_lists.append([1, 2])
...     return all_lists
... 
>>>
>>> list_of_list()
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

I've just appended `[1, 2]` everytime for demonstration purpose. You can add any list there.

Comment: @user2603519. Add it to your question.

Comment: Just create an empty list outside the for loop. And append `each` to that list where you are printing it.

Comment: Ahhh i see. Simple fix. I realise what was wrong now. i was trying to return the values to a list inside the for loop and as such what happened was it got overwritted each time.

Comment: @user2603519. Glad that you figured it out. :)

Comment: @user2603519. You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the arrow besides the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Rohit Jain suggested add a newlist outside the for loop and append.

What I had orginally was trying to append to a newlist inside the for loop. As such everytime the loop was run the values where calculated and produced in the each list and were added to the loop however it was overwritten as the list was not placed outside the list. As such to return a list from a list in a for loop you simple put a newlist at the front and append to that.

The answer is now updated in my code which works now.